# DataGrid event handling in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-4

I have a `DataGrid` and need to handle its events. I have a business logic to be implemented which needs to be handled in the `ViewModel` and able to unit test.

Can I raise events and handle them in the `ViewModel`?  In this case how to unit test?

Comment: Which events on the grid to you need to handle?  A grid does not have lots of interactivity to initiate business logic, hence my question.

Comment: I need to handle SelectedIndexChanged. In general wanted to know how to handle events in MVVM, as view should could not contain any code that handle logic.

Comment: Are you meaning the 'DataGrid' control?

Comment: Yes Datagrid events to be handled.

Comment: I edited the question so that it says DataGrids.  Moving on.  In the MVVM world, most people synch up the SelectedValue property and set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to true, and don't usually use the events.  Would an answer along those lines be suitable?

Comment: In case `SelectedIndexChanged`... **Don't** use an event, use `Binding` instead. Generally, you should trying to avoid using events in MVVM, since, IMHO, you can do almost everything with `Binding`, what you're trying to achieve by using events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EventTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030417/mvvm-view-event-viewmodel-command-binding) from System.Windows.Interactivity or MvvmLight

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myProtokollList">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding Path=OpenCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myProtokollList, Path=SelectedItem.OriginalSatzX}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```