# how to handle DataGrid event in ViewModel class

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to handle the DataGrid event in ViewModel class. Since there is no Command property in DataGrid it becomes very tough to handle events in DataGrid. I refered [Interaction.Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736154/datagrid-event-handling-in-wpf-mvvm) ,but that System.Windows.Interactivity.dll is giving some exception while building the project. please help me.

Comment: show some code and the exception you get

Comment: DataGrid events should be handled in the code behind of the view, as they are a UI element. If you post some code and/or error messages someone may be able to help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one example what i do in my projects. i use the mvvm light version from EventToCommand, but the  System.Windows.Interactivity.dll should work too

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              x:Name="myProtokollList"
              IsReadOnly="True" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="true"
              SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=OneWay}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <Commanding:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding Path=OpenCommand}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myProtokollList, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```